# How to increase div content value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to increase div value +1 in certain events.How can i get div value and increase it?

Comment: what do you mean div value? coordinates? dimensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given:

```
<div id="x">42</div>
```

You can do this:

```
var $x = $('#x');
$x.text(parseInt($x.text(), 10) + 1);
```

For your education:

- [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text)
- [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) (and always include the radix argument)

Comment: I like the initial number choice :P

Comment: I know 23 to be a number to which everything seems to be connected(like the movie 23). 11, however, I'm not sure... Is it because it's a double digit, signifying power?

Answer (score 1):

```
this.innerHTML = +this.innerHTML + 1;
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TejGJ/1/)**

Comment: You really should be using parseInt() on your string. Javascript allows you to be lazy, but that doesn't mean you should be.

Answer (score 0):

If the div's HTML is simply a number:

```
var element = document.getElementById('yourElementID');
element.innerHTML = parseInt(element.innerHTML, 10)+1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you use below code

```
In javascript
--------------
var demoInt = $('#divInt').text();
demoInt =parseInt(demoInt);

In HTML
-------
<div id="divInt">111</div>
```